# How to call from a 4g internet device

Tags: voip, gsm, 4g, voip-android, huawei-mobile-services

I have a Huawei e5573 4g device (connects to internet through 2g 3g or 4g via a regular sim card, same as that used in a mobile phone).
It can receive and send messages (sms) and ussd too.
I was wondering if there is any way of using the device to make voice calls with it from the sim inserted inside it, just like in as a phone ? 
Has anyone done that before ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using the device itself, then the answer is no as it does not have audio functionality - i.e. speaker and microphone.

It does support SMS as you say, if you log in to the router's web admin.

You can use any VoIP service over the date network, provided your network operator does not restrict or block them, but I am sure you know this.

There are some discussions on the web about opening the box and 'hacking' it, loading firmware etc but I suspect even if you found a way to get this to work it would be a very high effort / expensive way to just make a voice call device.